# My WordPress Website showing Sample page instead of Home?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I have transferred a domain form another registrar to my hostinger hosting plan I have been building the website on WordPress but my website shows sample page instead of Home page which i set in the homepage settings as static page.
Some help will be appreciated. is there any DNS record setting error or something else.

Comment: Looks like something is overriding  your wordpress backend settings.
Check your wp-config.php to see if homepage is defined there.

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursite.com/pagename' );